# Подключение к MySQL, запушенной на виртуалке, извне.

Tags: mysql, битрикс

На **VirtualBox** поднята ***Bitrix-овская CentOS 6***. Виртуалка доступна через сетевой мост, адрес интерфейса - **192.168.3.3**

Задача - подключиться к **MySQL** на виртуалке из **MySQL WorkBench** на локальной машине.

Вопрос - как узнать адрес и порт **MySQL**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Адрес и порт верные. А вот пользователя для работы с сервером нужно создать...

Comment: Запущен сайт на Bitrix, все работает. $DBLogin  и $DBPassword инициализированы корректно.

Comment: Я полагаю, что следовательно пользователь с таким именем существует. Нет?

Comment: А еще надо в my.cnf установить параметр bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 3):

1. Подключаемся к БД как root, вводим пароль

   ```
   mysql -uroot -p
   ```
2. Выбираем таблицу с настройками БД

   ```
   use mysql
   ```
3. Смотрим пользователей, которые могут конектится к БД. В поле Host будет стоять localhost (можно работать только с локального), IP или % (разрешено удаленное подключение)

   ```
   SELECT Host, User, Password FROM user;
   ```
4. Разрешаем руту (пишем любой доступный логин) подключаться к БД удаленно

   UPDATE user SET Host='%' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
5. Применяем настройки

   ```
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
6. Обратите внимание, что у вашего пользователя, который будет иметь удаленный доступ, должен стоять пароль. Если его нет, ставим

   ```
   UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('ПАРОЛЬ') WHERE User='root' AND Host='%';
   ```
7. Выходим

   ```
   quit;
   ```